# Nuget pack command produces wrong file name

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

I'm using `Nuget.exe v3.5` command line tool to package my nuget packages. 
One of the two packages uses a regular 4 dots version number `a.b.c.d` and it worked as expected.

```
C:\nuget\nuget.exe pack C:\useful-stuff\4.5.0.2\useful-stuff.nuspec -outputdirectory C:\useful-stuff-pkg\ -properties id=useful-stuff;version=4.5.0.2
>> useful-stuff.4.5.0.2.nupkg
```

But another package uses `yyyymmdd.c` version and the `nupkg` file produced has an extra `0`. It should be `useful-stuff2.20161221.0.nupkg` but instead, it got an extra and became `useful-stuff2.20161221.0.0.nupkg`. What am I doing wrong here?

```
C:\nuget\nuget.exe pack C:\useful-stuff2\20161221.0\useful-stuff2.nuspec -outputdirectory C:\useful-stuff2-pkg\ -properties id=useful-stuff2;version=20161221.0
>> useful-stuff2.20161221.0.0.nupkg
```

UPDATE:

I also tried to reversion the first one `usefull-stuff` from `4.5.0.2` to `20161221.0` and got it to produce `usefull-stuff.20161221.0.0.nupkg` which also had the extra `0`. That proves it's not the problem of the `useful-stuff2` package, but more likely `Nuget.exe` itself.

Seems like if the version has 3 groups of digits `a.b.c` then `Nuget.exe` does not add the additional `0`. So I think it's trying to make sure the version always has at least 3 groups of digits.